# Unity3D Show add every 5 restarts

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it to where when you restart the game it shows an advertisement after 5 times. This is what I have so far. This does not work. This was tested.

```
    private int restartNum {
        get {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("restartNum");
        }
        set {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("restartNum", value);
        }
    }

    public void OnButtonClick(string sceneName)
    {
        restartNum += 1;
        if (restartNum == 5) {// adding this makes it not work
            ShowAd ();// This works by itself
            restartNum = 0;
        }
        SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneName);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so what's happening? Did you test it? Does it work? You did not say if there is a problem.....

Comment: I thought it not working was obvious...I edited the question though

Comment: Not a good way to ask a question. You must state what your problem is in your question. Even after after editing it, you didn't mention what's currently happening now. You only said the "It doesn't work". I was able to track down the problem. Check my answer.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I will be more detailed next time.

Comment: That's fine. Can't wait to see your next question and you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (restartNum == 5)` will only restart when `restartNum` is `5` and this will be `true` only **once**. After that, `restartNum` will always be `> 5` and your `if` statement will **never** be true again. To get it work *every 5 times*, use the modulus operator (`%`).

Change your

```
if (restartNum == 5)
```

to

```
if (restartNum % 5 == 0)
```

It will divide `restartNum` by `5` each time and check if the remainder is `0`. If `0` then this is a 5th time.